# Invariant factors and elementary divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, smith-normal-form

> I have to find the characteristic polynomial, the minimal polynomial, the invariant factors and the elementary divisors of $M$, where $M=K^3$ is a $K[T]$-module for some field $K$ and $T$ acts as the matrix
> \begin{equation}
> \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
> 0&1&0 \\
> 0&0&0\\
> 0&0&1\\
> \end{array}
> \right)
> \end{equation}

In the problem above, I was able to find all the answers, but, being honest, I am not sure about them. The characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $\mathrm{char}_T(x) = \det(xI-T) = x^2(x-1)$. The minimal polynomial must have the same roots, thought, it must be $x(x-1)$ or $x^2(x-1)$, but with minimal degree such that $\min_T(T)=0$. Since $T(T-1) \neq 0$ and $T^2(T-1)=0$, we conclude that $\min_T(x)=x^2(x-1)$. This way, by the Structure Theorem, $$M \simeq K^3[x]/\langle x^2(x-1) \rangle.$$

My bigger problem is finding the invariant factors and the elementary divisors. Could someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 1):

Invariant factors: only one $x^2(x-1)$.

Applying  [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem):

$$
K[x]/\left<x^2(x-1)\right>\cong K[x]/x^2\oplus K[x]/(x-1).
$$

Then the elementary divisors are $\{x^2, x-1\}$.